# Which category for scholarship money in GnuCash

Tags: gnucash

I use GnuCash for home accounting. In particular I use it to keep track of college expenses. Where should scholarship money received from the college go? One side of the entry will be a reduction of expenses. But where does the other side go? As Income?

Comment: is it being used to reimburse you for past expenses, or is it for future expenses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be income. You can add an income account to specifically track scholarships separately if other sources of income.